# tensorflow error: index out of bounds? Training data multiplied *3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, training-data

I have a problem with the training of a CNN.
My dataset has currently 1000 numpy arrays containing an image and a list.

This is the code used to train the CNN:

```
import numpy as np
from alexnet import alexnet

# image resolution
WIDTH = 160
HEIGHT = 120

LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 8
MODEL_NAME = 'model-{}-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, 'alexnet',EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

hm_data = 22

for i in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in range(1,hm_data+1):
        train_data = np.load('trainmodel_test1.npy'.format(i))

        train = train_data[:-100]
        test = train_data[-100:]

        X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        Y = [i[1] for i in train]

        test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

        # ----------- error happens here: ----------------
        model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=EPOCHS, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),
            snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
        # ------------------------------------------------

        model.save(MODEL_NAME)
```

it initiates:

---

```
Training samples: 2700           # -----> expected: 900 !!!
Validation samples: 300          # -----> expected: 100 
--
```

but the problem is now that it multiplies the dataset *3 and complains afterwards that the indexes are higher than the total dataset range:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\Python\Python35\Lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "..\Python\Python35\Lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "..\0.1\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "..\0.1\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "..\0.1\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
IndexError: index 1331 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 900
```

hints on that?

*~modified code by sentdex*

Comment: share what's `X.shape, Y.shape, test_x.shape and test_y.shape`

Comment: General advice, it doesn't make sense to use `i` for two different for loops. change one of them.

Comment: Did you solve this please, as I have the same problem?

Comment: @hurkaperpa I used another model "inceptionnet_v3" instead of alexnet and it worked.